# SQL Server query - Min, Max, Avg aggregates issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, average, min

I would like to have some statistic data (min, max, average) from a database but I am currently facing a problem. I think the syntax is incorrect but I am not sure. I can not get expected results.

Here is the table;

```
name          period    b   c   
-----------------------------
KONYA       July - 2014 7   3   
KONYA       July - 2014 8   5   
KONYA       July - 2014 9   9   
KARAMAN     July - 2014 5   2   
KARAMAN     July - 2014 4   5   
LYON        July - 2014 5   1   
LYON        July - 2014 6   9   
LYON        July - 2014 7   7
```

Here is what I expect;

```
name          period      max(b)    min(b)   max(c) min(c) ...  
--------------------------------------------------------------
KONYA       July - 2014     9        7         9      3
KARAMAN     July - 2014     5        4         5      2
LYON        July - 2014     7        5         9      1
```

And my sql query;

```
SELECT 
    name,
    max(b), max(c), min(b), min(c)
FROM 
    tablename
GROUP BY 
    name, b, c;
```

Could you please help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should only be GROUP'ing on 'name'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `b,c` from `group by` and add `period` instead

```
SELECT name,period,
max(b), max(c), min(b), min(c)
FROM tablename
group by name,period
```